# laravel : return view not return from based route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have an issue in Laravel routing. I am able to go to the following routes independently:

```
localhost/project/public/profile/profileSetup
localhost/project/public/thread/AddTrade
```

But, if I am on the route `localhost/project/public/thread/AddTrade` and if I click on the profile setup page link, I am redirected to `localhost/project/public/thread/profile/profileSetup` path instead of `localhost/project/public/profile/profileSetup`.

In my controller:

```
return view('profile.profileSetup')->with('data',$userProfile);
```

In my route:

```
Route::get('profile/profileSetup', array('uses'=>'ProfileController@ProfileSetup'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use named route to redirect.

Define Route like this:

```
 Route::get('profile/profileSetup', array('uses' => 'ProfileController@ProfileSetup','as'=>'myroute'));
```

and in you view:

```
<a href="{{{ URL::route('myroute') }}}"></a>
```

This will set the href attribute accordingly.